# Linear algebra, vector space

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $F\colon \mathbf R^n\times \mathbf R^n\to \mathbf R$ is the function $F(x,y)=\left<Ax,y\right>$, where $\left<,\right>$ is the standard inner product of $\mathbf R^n$ and $A$ is a $n\times n$ real matrix. Here $D$ denotes the total derivative.which of the following statements are correct?

1. $[DF(x,y)](u,v)=\left<Au,y\right>+\left<Ax,v\right>$.
2. $[DF(x,y)](0,0)=0$
3. $DF(x,y)$ may not exist for some $(x,y)\in \mathbf R^n×\mathbf R^n$.
4. $DF(x,y)$ does not exixt at $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. We have for $x,y,u,v \in \mathbf R^n$: 
\begin{align*}
  F(x+u, y+v) &= \def\<#1>{\left<#1\right>}\<Ax+Au, y+v>\\
       &= \<Ax,y> + \<Ax,v> + \<Au,y> + \<Au,v>\\
       &= F(x,y) + \<Ax, v> + \<Au,y> + o(\left\|(u,v)\right\|)
\end{align*}
From this you can read of all answers.

Comment: Please solve clealy and how o(||(u,v)||)?